# Binary search in C language

Tags: c

What is the problem with the next code ? 
It is a code for making a binary search between the elements of an array that we fill randomly using the rand() function. We use here the function bin_sear to sort and return for us a boolean value true if the element we seek is found in our table and flase if the element we dont find doesent figure in our table. The code doesent work. So where is the error here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

bool bin_sear(int k[] ,int s , int target );

int main()
{
int a[10];
int i,j;
char k;
bool bin;

while(1){
srand(time(NULL));
// we fill our table
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    a[i]=rand()%101+1;

  }
printf("Please enter the element you are seeking for: ");
scanf("%d",&j);

  if(bin_sear(a[10],10,j)==true){
  printf("The element you seek exists in our array");
  }
  else {
    printf("The element you are seeking doesent exist in our array");
  }
        if (k=='n'){
    break;
  }
}

return 0;
}


bool bin_sear(int k[],int s, int target){

int i,j,pos,aux,low,high,test;

for (i=0;i<s;i++){
    pos=i;
    for (j=i;j<s;j++){
        if (k[j]<pos){
            pos=j;
        }
     aux=k[pos];
     k[pos]=k[i];
     k[i]=aux;
    }
}
low=0;
high=s;


while (low<high-1){

     test=(low+high)/2;

if (target<k[test]){

    high=test;


}
else low=test;
}

if (target==k[test]){

    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: How should we know.  You don't tell us anything meaningful.

Comment: Even if I knew I wouldn't answer.  You've made no effort at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of errors in your code.

You need to call `bin_sear` with the pointer to the array, not element `a[10]` (which will give you an immediate segmentation fault):

```
if(bin_sear(a[10],10,j)==true){
```

should be

```
  if(bin_sear(a,10,j)==true){
```

Next - take a look at your bubble sort routine. You have the indices wrong, and the braces in the wrong place, and you are comparing a value to an index with your `if` statement. Modify it to this, and you will get a sorted array:

```
for (i=0;i<s-1;i++){
    pos=i;
    for (j=i+1;j<s;j++){
        if (k[j]<k[i]){
            pos=j;
            aux=k[pos];
            k[pos]=k[i];
            k[i]=aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you don't seem to set the value of `k` anywhere, so you have an infinite loop. Fix all that, and things will work a little bit better. Recommend you put a lot of `printf` statements in your code if this is not enough (and use a smaller range of random numbers initially to improve your chances of a hit).

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

bool bin_sear(int k[] ,int s , int target );

int main()
{
int a[10];
int i,j;
char k;
bool bin;

while(1){
srand(time(NULL));
// we fill our table
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    a[i]=rand()%10+1;
  }

  printf("Please enter the element you are seeking for: \n");
  // scanf("%d", &j); // not scanning input since this is codepad
  j = 5;
  printf("you entered: %d\n", j);
  fflush(stdout);

  if(bin_sear(a,10,j)==true){
    printf("The element [%d] exists in our array\n", j);
  }
  else {
    printf("The element [%d] doesn't exist in our array\n", j);
    printf("The array contains:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    printf("%d\n", a[9]);
  }
   printf("Would you like to test for another element?\n");
  // k = getchar();
  k = 'N'; // simulating user pressing uppercase N
  if(tolower(k) == 'n') {
     printf("goodbye!\n");
     break; // do this only once
  }
}

return 0;
}


bool bin_sear(int k[],int s, int target){

int i,j,pos,aux,low,high,test;

printf("starting to sort\n");
fflush(stdout);
for (i=0;i<s-1;i++){
    pos=i;
    for (j=i+1;j<s;j++){
        if (k[j]<k[i]){
            printf("swapping %d and %d\n", i, j); fflush(stdout);
            pos=j;
            aux=k[pos];
            k[pos]=k[i];
            k[i]=aux;
        }
    }
}
printf("sort finished\n");
printf("elements now:\n");
for(i = 0; i < s; i++) printf("k[%d] = %d\n", i, k[i]);
fflush(stdout);
low=0;
high=s;


while (low<high-1){

     test=(low+high)/2;

if (target<k[test]){

    high=test;


}
else low=test;
}

if (target==k[test]){

    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

Comment: The sorting algorithm is inside the bin_sear function.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Never mind then.

Comment: How can I pass the elements of the array by reference to a functıon

Comment: The name of the array is the pointer to the elements - so that's your "pass by reference" right there. I updated with working code ([written on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/qS9joYY6), so there is no user interaction; I'm sure you can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1):

`if(bin_sear(a[10],10,j)==true){` => `if(bin_sea(a, 10, j) == true)` from a quick glance. You need to pass the array into the function, `a[10]` would try to index the eleventh elment of the array, is also the wrong type (being an `int` instead of an array), and will probably cause an access violation exception, because the array is only ten elements long. Lots of errors for four characters, eh?

Comment: and such an error should be detected by the compiler...

Comment: Exactly.  The actual code hasn't been posted.

Comment: But OP didn't really specify whether it was a compiler error or runtime error, and if he's not proficient enough at C to avoid such mistakes, he might not be able to read the compiler errors well enough to find it. Eh, my logic at least.

Comment: Maybe so, but SO isn't a free learning center.  Questions are expected to demonstrate a minimum level of effort and competence.  If the OP is unable to tell us what's wrong, then he's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to write a function which sorts the array and then makes the binary search. You should separate the two algorithms, otherwise a linear search would be more efficient.

Comment: How can I pass the element of a table to an function by reference ?